# Update Post-Build with custom nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, events, msbuild, nuget

I need help to be able to update the post-build event of a project thanks to a custom nuget package.

I've created a package thanks to a nuspec file that include a .targets file :

```
<file src="*.targets" target="build"/>
```

Here is the .targets file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="Build" >
      <Message Text="Hello World" Importance="high" />    
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Actually, the file is read when i install the package (if i delete some '>', i've an error).
But the .csproj isn't updated (so, nothing in the post-build event textbox).

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Your .targets file needs to be named after the package id. Also the .targets file will be added as an Import element. Do you see an Import for it? The contents of the file will not be added to the project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Matt Ward. From NuGet 2.5, NuGet recognizes a new top-level folder: \build.

> Within the \build folder, you can provide a “.props” file and/or a
>   “.targets” file that will be automatically imported into the project.
>   For this convention, **the file name must match your package id** with
>   either a “.props” or “.targets” extension.

Please refer to the MSBuild Integration part in following document:

http://blog.nuget.org/20130426/native-support.html

And after install the package, you will see a import node in .csproj which import the package.targets file. Then when build your project, you will see "Hello World" text in output window.
[image]